# Is it feasible to perform signing with a private key inside a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, private-key, gas-price, keystore

Is it possible/feasible to have a private key stored inside a smart contract and sign transactions with it or would the calculations be to pricey in gas?
For example a smart contract should create signed transactions and the costs should be not much more than the transaction cost itself

Answer (score 3):

If you store something in a smart contract, then anyone can see it. It's no longer private, so anyone can take it and sign something. So, technically, you *could* store a private key inside a smart contract and write the smart contract to sign transactions (which would be fairly expensive), but it would be expensive and insecure since anyone could grab the private key.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. The essence of "private" key is that it is "private". You can write it down on a piece of white paper and keep it in a safe. The white paper should never go outside of your sight. The smart contract, however, is exposed to public eyes. Since everybody could see it, we can't call it a private key anymore.